# regex separating phone number and extension

Tags: regex

I'm running into some difficulty having a regex pattern match a phone number or extension, but not both (this way I can separate them.)

Pattern I'm using: 
`\(?<number>d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(?<extension>\d{4})/g`

The problem here is `\d{4}` is in both of them, so it's not sufficiently separating the two. I was thinking a lookaround may be the answer, but I can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Some examples of input and expected results would be nice (please edit the question). Phone number formats are different around the world.

Comment: for example, 973-252-0392 and also x4386

Comment: `(?<number>\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(?<!\d{3}-\d{3}-)(?<extension>\d{4})`

Comment: Can you please take away the downvote, I had an honest question and I wasn't being inflammatory. I am trying to get enough reputation so I can upvote all of the people who help me and I don't even have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample input it's hard to guess what you are looking for. Here is an example how to separately parse the number and extension, assuming an arbitrary extension prefix you might have:

```js
var re = /(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(^|[^\-])(\d{4})/;
var str1 = 'number 111-222-3333';
var str2 = 'x4444';
var str3 = str1 + ' ' * str2;

if(re.test(str1)) {
  var num = RegExp.$1;
  var ext = RegExp.$3;
  console.log('str1, num: ' + num + ', ext: ' + ext);
}

if(re.test(str2)) {
  var num = RegExp.$1;
  var ext = RegExp.$3;
  console.log('str2, num: ' + num + ', ext: ' + ext);
}

if(re.test(str3)) {
  var num = RegExp.$1;
  var ext = RegExp.$3;
  console.log('str3, num: ' + num + ', ext: ' + ext);
}
```

Output:

```
str1, num: 111-222-3333, ext: 
str2, num: , ext: 4444
str3, num: 111-222-3333, ext:
```

Comment: Where do these tags `<number>` & `<extension>` come from?

Comment: @Toto: From the regex in the original question: `<number>d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}` etc

Comment: In the question they are [Names capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) not xml tags.

Comment: @Toto: Ah, you are right. I was not familiar with the Python specific regex extension, and the question did not have the python tag. I updated the answer accordingly.